# enviar $_FILE de un formulario a otra pagina con target _blank

Tags: php, html, formularios

Tengo un formulario con un input file para subir imágenes, no utilizo ajax ni nada porque salta a otra pagina para hacer un preview y no se porque en la variable $_FILE llega vacío. el resto de campos llegan correctamente.

Aquí el código:

extracto de preview.php

```html
<form method="post" name='contactform' id='contactform' action="guardarpdf.php" target="_blank">
    <input type="file"  name="logon" id="logon" accept=".jpg,.png">
</form
```

y el extracto de guardarpdf.php

```php
if (!empty($_FILES['logon'])){//Nunca llega a entrar aqui y/o hago echo y no saca nada
    echo "logon";
    $image = basename($_FILES['logon']['name']);
    $image_temp = $_FILES['logon']['tmp_name'];
    list($base,$extension) = explode('.',$image);
    $newname = implode('.', [$base, time(), $extension]);
    $ruta = "uploads";
    $ruta = $ruta."/".$newname;
    move_uploaded_file($image_temp,$ruta);
    ?>
    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $newname; ?>" style="width: 100%;">
    <?php
    $logo=$newname;
}
?>
```

Comment: imprime la variable $_FILES para revisar

Comment: Para permitir envío de archivos, la etiqueta `<form ...>` debe incluir la propiedad `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Referencia: https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=541:enctype-multipartform-data-html-seleccionar-archivo-type-file-en-formularios-ejemplo-basico-cu00725b&catid=69&Itemid=192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca el atributo **`enctype`**

```
<form method="post" name='contactform' id='contactform' action="guardarpdf.php" target="_blank" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file"  name="logon" id="logon" accept=".jpg,.png">
</form>
```

Comment: yo pensando que era por el target y no me había dado cuenta de la falta del enctype... Gracias.